# How to drop specific observations from dataset in Stata?

Tags: command, stata

I have a large dataset but I do not need all observations. The dataset contains data for every day within the period from 1989 to 2019. How can I delete all observations in Stata except for the last day of each year and per each firm?

So 12/31/1989, 12/31/1990,12/31/1991....12/31/2019 should be kept. (the variable name and format is attached with the image)

Thank you very much!
Best regards
Sven

[Overview about dataset format/variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74iVZ.png)

Answer (score 2):

```
gen year = year(DATE)
bysort PERMNO year (DATE) : keep if _n == _N
```

Comment: Thank you! A mistake on my part: the observations should only refer to the last day of the year, but per company. How do I get the dataset to show me the data for the period per company?

Comment: Updated my answer. Please edit the question to include this information for people who may find this post in the future.